# Separate the elements of a row

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a $\psi$:

```
{a,b,c,d,e,...}
```

for example for 10 letters. How can I change it in the format:

```
 {{a},{b},{c},{d},{e},...}
```

I cannot understand why `Transpose` doesn't work for this aim!?

Comment: I would just use Map?  `Map[List, L]` where `L` is your original list.  screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1sIw.png) Transpose works on matrix (list of lists) not one a flat list like you have.

Comment: If you must use `Transpose` you can do `Transpose[{L}]` screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoVf0.png)

Comment: "The Wolfram Language makes no distinction between "row" and "column" vectors." [`ref`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LinearAlgebra.html) What are you trying to accomplish that requires the additional list brackets?

Comment: I understood my mistake

Comment: I could even use `ArrayReshape`

Comment: Also: `Partition[{a, b, c, d, e}, {1}]` or `Outer[List, {a, b, c, d, e}]`

Comment: Yes, there are at least 10 different ways to do the same thing in Mathematica :)

Comment: With `psi = Table[a[i], {i, 1, 10}];` we have the following 11 ways
`Transpose[{psi}]` and 
`Thread[{psi}]` and 
`Map[List, psi]` and 
`MapThread[List, {psi}]` and 
`Outer[List, psi]` and 
`DeleteDuplicates /@ Inner[List, psi, psi, List]` and 
`Partition[psi, {1}]` and 
`Flatten[{psi}, {2}]` and 
`ArrayReshape[psi, {Length@psi, 1}]` and 
`Tuples@{psi}` and 
`Subsets[psi, {1}]` giving the desired result. Kudos to @Nasser and @ 
E. Chan-López for doing awesome stuff as usually